# The Sato-Tate conjecture (Frobenius eigenvalues)

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Another question crossed my mind.

In the statement of the Sato-Tate conjecture, one usually assumes that 
the elliptic curve has no CM. But, I read the [Morita's paper](http://kazuma-morita.jimdo.com/app/download/12319896690/Sh.BSD.pdf?t=1452154642) for the BSD in the CM 
case and if it is true, it follows that the number of arguments $\{\theta\}$ of the Frobenius eigenvalues 
on the Tate module of the CM elliptic curve is **finite** up to multiplication by $\sqrt{p}$ or split prime ideal, that is, the eigenvalues 
are of the form (root of unity)$\times$($\sqrt{p}$ or split prime ideal). See the examples of Silverman's ``Advanced" book.

Though I know that the Sato-Tate conjecture for the CM case is easier because the L-function of the CM elliptic curve is written as a product 
of two Hecke L-functions, my question is:

the eigenvalues of the CM elliptic curve are essentially of the form (root of unity)?

Because some examples feel me so and 
I could not find errors in his paper, I am embarrassed.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: You are quite right to so. Sorry. I want to ask if the eigenvalues of the CM elliptic curve are so simple. I modified my question.

Comment: The Frobenius eigenvalues are the values of the underlying Hecke character by Deuring's theorem (Theorem 10.5 in Silverman's "Advanced Topics" books). So yes, they are so simple.

Comment: Thank you. I know that the L-function of the CM elliptic curve is written as a product of two Hecke L-functions and eigenvalues are simple. I asked if one can write  (root of unity)$\times$( $\sqrt{p}$ or split prime ideal)?

Comment: When the elliptic curve has CM by a class number one ring then the eigenvalues of Frobenius are $\pm \sqrt{p}$ for the inert primes and $\pi,\bar{\pi}$ if $p$ factors as $\pi \bar{\pi}$ in the ring.

Comment: The $L$-function is either a single Hecke $L$-function or a product of two Hecke $L$-functions. Now Frobenius eigenvalues are complex numbers, while a "root of unity times a prime ideal" is an ideal, so it makes no sense to talk about the equality of the two. At any rate, a Frobenius eigenvalues is a value of the underlying Hecke character(s) of a number field $F$, so at a principal prime ideal $(a)$ it equals a root of unity (with finitely many possible values) times a product of $\chi_v(a_v)$'s, where $v$ is any archimedean place and $\chi_v:F_v^\times\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ is some character.

Comment: My writing ``prime ideal" was bad. And  as you say, the L-function is either a single Hecke L-function or a product of two Hecke L-functions (not only a product of two Hecke L-functions).  I am very Sorry and thank you for your comments.

Comment: No problem, what I wrote originally was also misleading. The point of my last comment is: even for a general number field there is a similar description as in Felipe Voloch's answer, as follows from the explicit description of Hecke characters as Grössencharacters.

Comment: Thanks to the comments of Felipe and GH from Mo, my dilemma has disappeared. The eigenvalues of the CM elliptic curve would be such a form as both people said. Thank you very much.　As pointed out, this comments move from answer. I am sorry to GH from MO.

Comment: Perhaps someone could compose an answer from the comments, and post it as an answer?